# nodejs error: when mysql query with params, and null error ocurrs, can not catch

Tags: mysql, node.js, null, crash, try-catch

in the `try...catch`, when `art` is `null` (not a obj), when insert db with `query`, it will ocurr a error which can not be catched, and the app crash.

why can catch this error?

and

how to fix this to be catched, avoid the app crash?

```
/*
insert db
*/
function addGrabsArticle(art) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            if (err) {
                resolve(null);
                return;
            }

            let sql = "insert into `archives`(`title`,`pubdate`,`type`,`cat`,`seokey`,`seodesc`,`content`,`images`,`isdel`,`ispublish`) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            let params = [
                art.title,
                Date.now() + "",
                1,  // article
                2,  // coding
                art.seokey,
                art.seodesc,
                art.content,
                JSON.stringify(art.images),
                0,
                0
            ];
            conn.query(sql, params, (err, result) => {

                pool.releaseConnection(conn);

                if (err) {
                    
                    resolve(null);
                    return;
                }
                if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
                    resolve(result.insertId);
                }
                
            });
        });
    });
}
```

```
        try {
            var artObj = grabUtils.deepCopy(artlist[i]);
            var art = await grabUtils.getContent(artObj, contentProc);

            var insertId = await addGrabsArticle(art);
            
            await grabUtils.sleep(2000);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are resolving your Promise instead of Rejecting it. Resolve as the name suggests would assume everything was Ok, when you reject from your Promise this would go to your catch block as it would internally throw an Exception which is eventually caught in the Catch block.

```
// reject here
if (err) {
   reject("Connection Failed");
   return;
}
// Reject wherever you are handling an error instead of resolve()
```

Would recommend reading more about Promises here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: resolve is my design for my work.    it is not the solution.